# Using $.length() to check for presence of <li> not working

Tags: jquery

I want to check if a list item already exists on the page before adding it.  My code below attempts to do this by checking the length of the ID for the list item.  However, no matter what my if statement always resolves to true.  Can someone tell me what the problem is?

```
function addSpotsToMarketTree(dmaName, spot) {
    var id = "#" + dmaName + "-spots";
    var liID = "#" + spot + "-" + dmaName;
    if ($(liID).length == 0) {
        $(id).append("<li id='" + liID + "'>" + spot + "</li>");
    }
}
```

Comment: " if statement always resolves to true" It means, probably, that your selector is incorrect. Nothing the tell without the view of liID variable (its value) and the HTML code

Comment: @Cheery, the liID is on the line above, being constructed from dmaName and spot.

Comment: Yes - what exactly are the values of "spot" and "dmaName"?

Comment: Try adding an `alert(liID);` before the `if` statement, see if it gives you a clue

Comment: what is `spot`? If it's a number - than your `liID` is not a valid `id`. All `id`-s in CSS must start with a letter

Comment: Here's an example of the IT <li id="#ABCD0001-Albany-Schenectady-Troy">ABCD0001</li>

Comment: @cambraca When I added the alert it always popped up with a zero

Comment: Someone named @scrappedcola posted the correct answer and then deleted it before I could accept it.  Please re-answer the question if you're reading this.  The issue was the # sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct copy of your code into jsFiddle seems to work as expected with a couple of assumptions about the IDs.  Are you sure you are building up the IDs correctly?

**Edit**

Looking again at your code, it looks like you are including the # in the ID of the created list item, meaning you are creating something like

```
<li id="#new-dma" />
```

This means that your selector will never match and so your if statement will always be true.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stevegreatrex/Pfane/)

Comment: I build the ID up only once and then assign it to a variable that I use for both the selector and for the creation of the list items.

Comment: You shouldn't include the # when you set the ID of the created list item

Comment: Yep, that was indeed the problem.  Can't believe I didn't catch that! Thanks for figuring it out.  Someone actually submitted the correct answer a few minutes before you and then inexplicably deleted it.  I'll accept yours :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( ! $(liID).length ) {
    // the selector is empty
}
```

Double check to make sure your selector is good.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working just fine so my guess is your IDs are not coming across correctly. Set a breakpoint at your `if` statement (firebug of webkit dev tools) and see what your `liID` is.

Comment: I just set a breakpoint as you suggested.  The selector ID matches the ID of the list item.  However, the codes inside the if statement still executes.